# MLE for the weights of multilayer perceptron assuming a negative binomial distribution

Tags: neural-networks, maximum-likelihood, negative-binomial-distribution

I am fitting a multilayer percepton with one hidden layer and $4$ neurons in this layer for regression. I need to calculate the likelihood for the outcomes because I need this for the BIC. All the literature I found assumes that $y \sim N(mlp(x_i,w), \sigma^2)$ but my outcome is not normally distributed. It rather follows a poisson or negative binomial distribution. How do I calculate the MLE for the weights then? 
If $y$ was normally distributed, it is easy because by minimizing $E(w) = \sum (y_i - mlp(x_i,w))^2$ with some stochastic gradient method I get the MLE. But I do not know how to find the MLE when I assume a non-normal distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MLE is a general framework, the same approach could be applied to other distributions. It's not that difficult to find function that you need to minimize with gradient descent. For example, MLE for poisson: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression#Maximum_likelihood-based_parameter_estimation

It's a bit more difficult for the negative binomial distribution because it has two parameters. In the gaussian distribution, there are also two parameters, but one of them is fixed (variance). For the negative binomial, you also need to fix one of the parameters. If you're interested in integer predictions then you need to fix parameter that corresponds to the probability of success. You can use similar approach in order to find log likelihood for the function that you need to optimize: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation

In general, both of these approaches follow the same procedure. First, you find log-likelihood for your estimations and then you apply gradient descent on the negative log-likelihood with respect to the parameter. Basically, you just create different loss functions for the neural network training. Of course, you need to use all your training samples in order to obtain the solution for the MLE.

Comment: Thanks! Okay so I understand that it is possible to use a different loss function. But why do I have to fix the other parameter? If I assume normality, I don't have to fix the variance but also estimate it via MLE after I obtained a MLE for the weights.
EDIT: so $\hat{\sigma}^2 = 1/n \sum (y_i - mlp(x_i, \hat{w}))^2$

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood you correctly. For the definition, it looks like $mlp$ effects only mean of the gaussian and input doesn't have any effect on variance. You can estimate variance after you find solution for the mean, but for that, you need to assume that it's fixed during MLE. Variance doesn't have an impact on the MLE since it's assumed to be constant and independent from the input (even though these assumptions might be false).

Comment: Okay, yes you're right, I think I confused "fixed" with "known".

Comment: Now I am not sure if I got correctly .. this is my log likelihood similar to wikipedia:
\begin{equation}
log L(r,w) = \sum \log(\Gamma(y_i +r)) - \sum \log(y_i!) -n \log(\Gamma(r)) + \sum y_i \log(\frac{r}{r+mlp(x_i,w)}) + n\log(\frac{r}{r+mlp(x_i,w)}) + n r \log(1-\frac{r}{r+mlp(x_i,w)})
\end{equation}
Now, when looking at the derivates (which I didn't post), $r$ depends on $mlp(x_i,w)$ and vice versa. SoI  cannot fix one parameter, but have to minimize over $w$ and $r$ at the same time.

Comment: not quite, on wikipedia they estimate $r$ from log likelihood, but in your case $r$ should be calculated using the network $r=mlp(x_i,w)$. Then it matches formulas on wikipedia. The only difference is that you do not adjust $r$ directly, you do it by adjusting $w$ parameter in the $mlp$. $r$ should play the same role as mean in the gaussian and probability $p$ as variance (since you keep it constant and independent from the input). I hope it helps

Comment: but why $r = mlp(x_i,w)$? I thought $mlp(x_i,w)$ is still the mean of $y$.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, you're right, you need to predict mean, but estimate $r$ parameter from it, so that $r=\frac{(1 - p) \cdot mlp(x_i, w)}{p}$

Comment: But then I have to estimated $p$ with MLE.. As far as I understand it, there is no way to either estimate $p$ or $r$ by MLE. The other parameter can be obtained as you defined in your comment. But, what I wonder, $r$ would be dependent on the input $x_i$. Does this make sense?

Comment: You can estimate $r$ using neural network, but this won't be prediction by itself (as you pointed before) unless you assume that $p$ is constant and $p=0.5$. In that case, $r=mlp(x_i,w)$. Also, you can predict $r$ and $p$ from the input data and use them to estimate mean which will be your prediction, but the loss function will use $r$ and $p$ directly.

Answer (score 0):

Two key points:

1. You can apply MLE on the likelihood function of any distribution:

$~~~~~~~\langle \hat w_1,...,\hat w_n \rangle = \text{arg}\,\max\limits_{w_1,...,w_n}\ \mathcal{L}(w_1,...,w_n \mid Data ) = \text{arg}\,\max\limits_{w_1,...,w_n}\ \mathcal{f}(Data \mid w_1,...,w_n  )$

2. If your $y$ vector was subsampled from a larger dataset, you can always assume asymptotic normality:

$~~~~~~~y~\dot\sim~ N(mlp(x_i,w), \sigma^2)$

Comment: Thanks for your help! I get the first point, but concearning the second, I thought about that too, but when exactly can I argue with asymptotics? My data just doesn't look like normal distributed and it has excess zeros, that's why I would assume it is zero-inflated neg. binomial distributed